# How to login with bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to develop a simple login with bootstrap modal and it is not working, so if any one help could me I would be very grateful for their kindness.

I don't have much knowledge about JavaScript or Bootstrap.

```js
function login(){
        
        var username=document.getElementsByName("username").value;
        var password=document.getElementsByName("password").value;
        if(username.value == null && password.value == null){
             $('.alert').show();
            
        }
         else{
       document.getElementById("wrongpassword").innerHTML="Thank u very much"; 
         }
    }
```

```css
.alert{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="modal1"  role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h3 class="modal-title text-center" style="color:#333366;"><strong>LOGIN TO FOOD SAVIOR</strong></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
  <div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" class="form-control" style="height:40px;" required>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
   <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" class="form-control" style="height:40px;" required>
   </div>
   <div class="text-center">
   <input type="submit" value="LOGIN" name="login_btn" id="login_btn" onclick="login()" class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color:#333366;height:40px;color:#ffffff">
   </div>
            
            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable fade in">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-hide="alert">&times;</button>
                    <p> You Entered Wrong Detail. Enter Again
                    </p>
            </div>
            
            <p id="wrongpassword"></p>
  <h4 class="text-center"><a href="#">Forget Password</a></h4>
  </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
  <h4 class="text-center">Don't have Account yet? Let's <a href="#modal2" data-toggle="modal">Sign up</a> its fun and easy!</h4>
            <div class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal"><p>Close</p></button>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <a href="#modal1" data-toggle="modal">
             <h5>Login</h5></a>
```

**strong text**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three main reasons why your code does not run as you intended:

- You are treating the return value of `getElementsByName` like a single DOM element, rather than a collection of elements. If you want the first element of the returned collection, add the indexed property access `[0]` after the function call.
- You are accessing the `value` property one too many times for your `username` and `password` elements. You already did it once when you created the variables; no need to do it again when you include them in your `if` statement.
- You probably meant to display the alert when `!username || !password` instead of when `username == null && password == null`, since `username` and `password` will always be strings (and thus never be `null`). You could compare them to the empty string (`username === '' || password === ''`), but casting each to a boolean is a terser way to achieve the same thing.

### Demo Snippet:

```js
function login() {
  var username = document.getElementsByName("username")[0].value;
  var password = document.getElementsByName("password")[0].value;
  
  if (!username || !password) {
    $('.alert').show();
  } else {
    document.getElementById("wrongpassword").innerHTML = "Thank u very much";
  }
}
```

```css
.alert { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="modal fade" id="modal1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
  
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h3 class="modal-title text-center" style="color:#333366;"><strong>LOGIN TO FOOD SAVIOR</strong></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" class="form-control" style="height:40px;" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" class="form-control" style="height:40px;" required>
        </div>
        <div class="text-center">
          <input type="submit" value="LOGIN" name="login_btn" id="login_btn" onclick="login()" class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color:#333366;height:40px;color:#ffffff">
        </div>

        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable fade in">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-hide="alert">&times;</button>
          <p> You Entered Wrong Detail. Enter Again
          </p>
        </div>

        <p id="wrongpassword"></p>
        <h4 class="text-center"><a href="#">Forget Password</a></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <h4 class="text-center">Don't have Account yet? Let's <a href="#modal2" data-toggle="modal">Sign up</a> its fun and easy!</h4>
        <div class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal"><p>Close</p></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<a href="#modal1" data-toggle="modal">
  <h5>Login</h5>
</a>
```

Comment: Glad to help! Good luck with the rest of your project.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are accessing the .value Property twice:

```
    function login(){

         var username=document.getElementsByName("username");
         var password=document.getElementsByName("password");
         if(username.value == null && password.value == null){
              $('.alert').show();

         }
         else{
       document.getElementById("wrongpassword").innerHTML="Thank u very much"; 
          }
     }
```

This should work.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting `username` and `password` all ready to the values:

```
    var username=document.getElementsByName("username").value;
    var password=document.getElementsByName("password").value;
```

So you can just write this:

```
    if(username == "" || password == ""){
```

And don't use `null`, just compare with empty strings. 
I'm thinking that you meant `||` instead of `&&`.

Answer (score 0):

You are use .value two time in you function so it was not working.
You have to change like below

```
function login(){

    var username=document.getElementsByName("username");
    var password=document.getElementsByName("password");
    if(username.value == null && password.value == null){
         $('.alert').css("display","block");

    }
     else{
   document.getElementById("wrongpassword").innerHTML="Thank u very much"; 
     }
}
```